# How I can shrink output from SQL Query in bash

Tags: mysql, sql, bash

How I can shrink my output from this SQL Query to only 1 or 0?

```
SELECT 
object_id,
IF (last_scan_date + INTERVAL 60 MINUTE > NOW(), 1, 0) AS download_correct
FROM `git_download_server`
WHERE object_id="573"
```

My actually output when I run it from bash it's (i need only status code 1 or 0):

```
573    1
```

Comment: remove `object_id, ` from query

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`MySQL` automatically evaluates conditionals to 1 or 0 so you could just do this without `object_id` in the `select`. Add a `distinct` if you have multiple rows per `object_id`, but only want one row in your output.

```
SELECT last_scan_date + INTERVAL 60 MINUTE > NOW() AS download_correct
FROM `git_download_server`
WHERE object_id="573";
```

Comment: Thanks, and if I want to stand for 1 or 3 instead of 1and 0?

Comment: @hock Not sure I understood that correctly. What you mean by 1 or 3? 1 and 0 are the default values when the condition is true and false respectively. If you want anything different, you could use a case statement. E.g `case when last_scan_date + INTERVAL 60 MINUTE > NOW() then 3 else 1 end as download_correct`